# Onto and one-one

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

> Let $f \colon A \to B$ be a surjection and $g \colon B \to C$ be such that
>   $g\circ f$ is an injection. Prove that both $f$ and $g$ are
>   injections.

Since $f$ is onto then there exists a $f(a)$ such that $f(a)=b$, for all $b\in B$. Now since $g\circ f$ is one-one then for $a,a'\in A$ we get that $ g(f(a)) \ne g(f(a'))$ implies that $f(a)\ne f(a')$. Then since $f(a)\ne f(a') \implies b=f(a)\ne f(a')=b'$ implies that $b\ne b'$ hence $g$ is also one-one.

I can't find a way to show that $f$ is one-one.

Can I just say that since  $b\ne b'$ and $f$ is onto then all of $b$ has an $a$ such that $f(a)=b$ but $f(a)\ne f(a')$ (which I proved above) thus $a\ne a'$ therefore $f$ is one-one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$f$ is injection:**
Suppose $a, a' \in A$ and $f(a) = f(a')$. Applying $g$ to both side gives $g\circ f(a) = g\circ f(a')$. Since $g\circ f$ is injection, we conclude that $a = a'$. This shows that $f$ is injection. (*Note that this is independent from the hypothesis that $f$ is surjection.*)

**$g$ is injection:**
Suppose $b, b' \in B$ and $g(b) = g(b')$. Since $f$ in surjection, there exists $a, a' \in A$ such that $b = f(a)$ and $b' = f(a')$. Hence we get $g\circ f(a) = g(b) = g(b') = g\circ f(a')$. Since $g\circ f$ is injection, $a = a'$ follows. Applying $f$ to both side gives $b = f(a) = f(a') = b'$. This shows that $g$ in injection.

**Edited:** Your proof in the question is wrong. To show the injectivity of $h$, you have to show that 
$$ h(x) = h(y) \implies x = y$$
as I did above or its contoraposition 
$$ x \neq y \implies h(x) \neq h(y) $$
for all $x$ and $y$. So your proof should be

1. *Assume* $b \neq b'$.
2. There exists $a, a' \in A$ such that $b = f(a)$ and $b' = f(a')$ since $f$ is surjection.
3. Hence $f(a) \neq f(a')$.
4. $a \neq a'$. Otherwise $f(a) = f(a')$, contradiction.
5. $g \circ f(a) \neq g \circ f(a')$ since $g \circ f$ is injection.
6. Therefore $g(b) \neq g(b')$.
7. Conclude $g$ is injection.

---

1. *Assume* $a \neq a'$.
2. $g \circ f(a) \neq g \circ f(a')$ since $g \circ f$ is injection.
3. Hence $f(a) \neq f(a')$. Otherwise $g \circ f(a) = g \circ f(a')$, contradiction.
4. Conclude $f$ is injection.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what I did wrong with my proof? And why did you say that since $f$ is onto then $a, a' \in A$ s.t $b=f(a)$ and $b'=f(a')$? I asked that because cant $f(a)$ also equal $b'$? $b'=f(a)$?

Comment: @Tom I edited my answer a little to answer your second question. I hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: @Tom I added my answer paragraphs which mentioned where your proof was wrong. It seems to me you misunderstand the definition of injection.

Comment: I ended up with $b \neq b'$ because $f(a) = b$ and $f(a')=b'$ and since $f(a)\ne f(a')$ then I implied $b \neq b'$. 

Should I have said that since $g\circ f$ is an one-one then $g\circ f(a) \neq g\circ f(a')$ implies that $a\ne a'$ thus $f$ is one-one?

Comment: @Tom Sorry, what you said is right --- ending up with $b \neq b'$ is nothing wrong. But to get $f(a) \neq f(a')$, you have to assume $a \neq a'$ first. Besides, injectivity of $g \circ f$ doesn't imply $g \circ f(a) \neq g \circ f(a) \implies a \neq a'$. In general, $P \implies Q$ is not equivalent of $Q \implies P$.

Comment: So I cant do $g \circ f(a) \neq g \circ f(a) \implies a \neq a'
$?

Comment: @Tom No, you can't. I added alternative proof along with the direction you did. I hope it makes clear.

Answer (score 0):

if $f$ is not one-to-one there exists $a\neq a'$ such that $f(a)=f(a')$ then $g(f(a))=g(f(a'))$ because $g$ is a function, but $g\circ f$ is one-to-one so $a=a'$ in contraddiction with hypotesis.

Comment: Thanks that is definitely a more convenient way to see that. Can you tell me what I did wrong with my proof?